# Tags: agile <- agile-development

Tags: discussion

I think `agile` and `agile-development` should be synonyms, but before I propose one, I thought I'd check:

- `agile` has 9 questions, whereas `agile-development` has 24.
- The tag pages are here:  [`agile`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) and  [`agile-development`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile-development)
- I think the master should be `agile`, since for UX.SE the term *agile development* refers overly to the development process whereas agile (and agile UX in particular) is a more encompassing approach.

I can fill out a tag definition and wiki for `agile`, but is there a protocol for proposing a less-popular tag as master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correctness matters more than popularity--I went and made them a synonym with Agile as the master.

Comment: great thanks.  i've proposed an excerpt definiion for the tag